# Rails html encoding in json problem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

Consider the following two scenarios:

**Ruby 1.8.7 Rails 2.3.2**

```
{:a => '<div style="color:red;">asd</div>'}.to_json
?> {"a":"\u003div style=\"color:red;\"\u003Easd\u003/div\u003E"}
```

this does not cause any problems when i do jQuery.parseJSON()

**Ruby 1.8.7 Rails 3.0.9**

```
{:a => '<div style="color:red;">asd</div>'}.to_json
?> {"a":"<div style=\"color:red;\">asd</div>"}
```

this causes error - **JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object** when i do jQuery.parseJSON()

Have tried the following:

- ::Iconv.conv('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8', self + ' ')[0..-2]
- .html safe
- JSON.encode

None are working. This is really killing me!

Thanks in advance.

**Update :** The json renderer

```
render :text => {:success => true, :replacement => '<div style="color:red;">asd</div>'}.to_json
```

also tried

```
render :json => {:success => true, :replacement => '<div style="color:red;">asd</div>'}
```

Comment: Hmm, need more context. This works for me: `$.parseJSON("{\"a\":\"<div style=\\\"color:red;\\\">asd</div>\"}")`. Can you show the exact text that's being passed to `$.parseJSON`, pulled from the AJAX call or HTML page, not from the REPL?

Comment: The exact text parsed is a bit large. But my senses say that there isn;t issue with the parsing but with the way json is being rendered, as the parsing didn't cause errors in rails2.3.2

Comment: I agree, but I wonder whether the problem is not with a change in the JSON encoder itself, but a problem later on with how the JSON string is handled (e.g. it's being encoded for HTML, which it shouldn't be). If the JSON encoder changed, it might reveal another problem like this.

Comment: Could you look at the sting that's ending up in `$.parseJSON`'s hands? How's it being loaded: is it included inline in a script, being loaded  asynchronously from another file, or something else?

Comment: the json comes as a response for an ajax request. not inline. has the way to render json changed in rails 3? i feel i am missing something very basic here

Comment: Could you please post the code that issues & responds to the ajax request?

Comment: @ZX12R : Are you still having this issue? If so, could you post your Controller who is handling the request?

Comment: @fishz: by controller you mean the action method or the entire controller?